# Is the "top" of a stack different from both the start and the end?

Tags: c, libyaml

I'm using the C libYAML library for handling YAML configuration files, and I a little confused about this struct element in its code:

```
/** The stack of mapping pairs (key, value). */
struct {
    /** The beginning of the stack. */
    yaml_node_pair_t *start;
    /** The end of the stack. */
    yaml_node_pair_t *end;
    /** The top of the stack. */
    yaml_node_pair_t *top;
} pairs;
```

It uses three pointers, `start`, `end`, and `top`. Both `start` and `end` seem obvious, they're the beginning and end of the region of data, but what is `top`?

(For reference, this code appears at line 741 [here](http://pyyaml.org/browser/libyaml/branches/stable/include/yaml.h?rev=372#L741).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start and end refer to the maximum boundaries of the stack.  The top is a dynamic pointer referring to the current position, and changes as you call nested levels of functions.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. So if a pointer is within the stack, less than `end`, but greater than `top`, it isn't used yet?

Comment: @JakeKing correct, except it would depend on the implementation details of the stack - it is free to grow forwards from `start` to `end`, or backwards from `end` to `start`.  And that's assuming `end` is greater than `start`.